# Suspension of a topological space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, manifolds

Let $X$ be a topological space such that its suspension is a topological manifold. Can we prove that $X$ itself is a topological manifold?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It’s not true. The Poincare sphere $P$ is a manifold, and its suspension is not. But its double suspension is homeomorphic to $S^5$ by Cannon’s “Double Suspension Theorem”.  I learned about this from Mark Grant in an answer to a different question of mine on MO.

Answer (score 14):

As Jeff Strom said, the answer is no. For references to Cannon-Edwards theorem, see https://mathoverflow.net/a/316175/121665.

Comment: Another related MO question is [Is a map a homotopy equivalence if its supension is so?](https://mathoverflow.net/a/46939).